# CI session userdata empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, continuous-integration

In my CI project Session userdata returns empty string. I have tried to config session variables in config.php but i'm unable to fix this issue. Can anyone helps me to fix?

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
//$config['cookie_domain']  = "";
// $config['cookie_path']       = "/";
$config['cookie_path'] = str_replace('//','/',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/');
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Did you define any userdata? If your answer is yes, please add your code here.

Answer (score 0):

You should define it first.

Open application/config/autoload.php and load `session` library:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Than edit this code the way you like:

```
$session = array(
 'somekey' => 'somevalue',
 'otherkey' => 'othervalue'
);
$this->session->set_userdata($session);
```

If you want to reach that values, use this:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('somekey');
```